# Why is my setState in useState working the opposite way?

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, checkbox, react-typescript

I am implementing a select all checkbox in typescript.

This is what it looks like:
[image]
The checkbox besides "Songs" is the select all checkbox,but when it turns to checked, the other checkboxed become unchecked,and become checked when it is unchecked,just like the picture shows.

It works fine in the first few change, but failed after about three change.

Here is my code:

```js
const [check, setCheck]=useState(false);
async function allCheck(e:any){
  console.log(e.target.checked);
  setCheck(e.target.checked);
  console.log(check);
  e.stopPropagation();
  cards.forEach(async (card) =>{
    console.log(card);
    await updateCard(card.id, {
      checked : check,
    });
    let song=document.getElementById(card.id);
    console.log(song);
    if(song){
      let checkbox=song.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]') as HTMLInputElement;
      if(checkbox){
        checkbox.checked = card.checked;
      }
    }
  });
  fetchCards();
}
```

Here is what the javascript console prints when the top checkbox is checked:
[image]
true is for `console.log(e.target.checked)`
and false is for `console.log(check)`

Why is this happening?And I also want to know how to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: Please see this link for further information. `useState` does not update until the next render https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately

Comment: You could use e.target.checked instead of check inside the foreach.

Comment: Ok! thank you both!